# reusing the returned object from operator function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Consider the following operator overloading scenario

```
class integer
{
   public:
   int a;
   integer()
   {
        a = 0;
   }
  friend integer operator+(integer &a ,int b);
};
integer operator+(integer &a,int b)
{
    a.a = a.a + b;
    return a;
}
int main()
{
   integer obj;
   integer obj2;
   obj+2; //Line 1.  this works.
```

The `operator+` function returns an object of `integer` type.So why can't i execute a function call like

```
(obj+2)+3; //no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'integer' and 'int')
```

While this works

```
obj2 = obj+2;
obj2+3;
```

Comment: `(obj+2)` returns a temporary. Temporaries can't bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: Taking a step back, you've named your operator `+`, but it behaves like `+=`. This will end in tears.

Comment: Simply making operator+ take a const integer & a and making it not modify the reference, but modify a new integer that you return will make this work as you want, and as it should with regards to what @IgorTandetnik said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`integer &a` means that `a` can only refer to an lvalue. But `obj+2` is not an lvalue.

To fix this, you should change your parameter to `integer a`, which:

- can bind to rvalues
- makes your function actually perform `operator+`'s function.

If your first parameter is `integer&` it would suggest you are trying to write `operator+=`. For that function, the solution would be to also return `integer&`, so that `obj+=2` is an lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

As a corollary to M.M's answer (which you should accept), here is the fixed code:

```
class integer
{
   public:
   int a;
   integer()
   {
        a = 0;
   }
  friend integer operator+(integer a ,int b);
};

// fix: arg 1 passed by value
integer operator+(integer a,int b)
{
    a.a = a.a + b;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
   integer obj;
   integer obj2;
   obj+2;
  (obj+2)+3;
}
```